# How did the hubble deep field took pictures of far away galaxies?

Tags: astronomy, telescopes

Milyway has a radius of ~27K ly. Is our galaxy like a net with large holes that the light from another galaxy could pass straight through these holes and reach us on earth ? Theoretically, is it possible to shoot an arrow from earth to one of the galaxies shown on deepfield pictures ? On its way, I feel the arrow will probably hit an astroid/comet in oort cloud with in our solar system itself ?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solar system, galaxies, and the universe itself is quite empty as far as opaque objects are concerned.  Think of how much space there is between Earth and the moon.  Most things that pass closer to Earth than the moon don't end up hitting the moon because the moon takes up a very small fraction of the spherical volume it orbits in.  It is the same for the solar system (planets/minor bodies taking up a very small fraction of the volume of the system itself), and for galaxies (stars and opaque nebulae taking up a very small fractions of the volume of galaxies).

Thus, there is a lot of empty space to point telescopes towards and see outside our galaxy.  Your "net with large holes" idea is on the right track, but doesn't truly capture just how much empty space there is in space.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you. Wiki says average distance between objects in asteroid belt is $10^9m$, and for objects in Oort cloud it is $10^{11}m$ . These are huge gaps indeed! If you're on an asteroid in asteroid belt you wont even see any other asteroid nearby. Really not the picture I've been imagining so far! Giess its due to relying too heavily on movies like Startrek for queries on astronomy ;)